# What prevents an SSL certificate holder to issue new 'valid' certificates

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

I am new to **SSL certificate**s and trying to wrap my head around this concept. As per my understanding when a valid certificate is signed (by one of the many official CAs) it can also sign a certificate that is part of the same SSL trust chain - after all every certificate has a **public-private key pair**.
Lets consider the following example:

A certificate is issued for `example.com` and sing by and intermediate certificate:

```
root cert -> intermediate cert -> example.com cert
```

Now a browser can verify that `example.com` has a valid certificate by following the certificate chain up until the root cert.
What happens if the `example.com` decides to sign (using its own private key) a certificate for another entity `untrusted.com`? Now we have the following certificate chain:

```
root cert -> intermediate cert -> example.com cert -> untrusted.com
```

Lets say a client tries to establish a secure connection with `untrusted.com`. The browser will validate the `untrusted.com's` certificate by using `example.com's` **public key**. Then it will verify that `example.com's` certificate is also valid by using `intermediate's` public key ... and this will go all the way down to the valid `root certificate`. Is there a rule that prevents long certificate chains or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `example.com cert` is not a CA, so a browser won't use it to trust `untrusted.com`.

Comment: Whether or not a certificate can be used to sign another certificate is defined by the *basic constraints* field of the certificate.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/249347/what-differentiates-a-ca-cert-from-a-server-cert for more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding SSL certificate signing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38949/understanding-ssl-certificate-signing)

Comment: @DavidZ yes, it does answer my question perfectly! Thank you!